# Exception occur in line 23

Tags: java, exception

[image]I am trying to solve a program an exception is occuring again and again i dont know why help me out here is my code

```
import java.util.*;
public class Fashion
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    int sum=0;
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the number of judges");
    int x=in.nextInt();
    int a[]=new int[x];
    if((x<20)&&(x%2==1))
       {
       System.out.println("score given by judges");
       for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
         {
         a[i]=in.nextInt();
         }
       }
    int mid=(1+x)/2;
       for(int k=0;k<mid;k++)
       {
        if(a[mid+k]==a[mid-k])    //exception here why 
         {
         sum=sum+a[mid+k];
         }
       }
    System.out.println("the number get by the contestant is "+sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any particular exception ?

Comment: What exception?  What is the exact error message that you get?  Which line of code does it correspond to?

Comment: what exception? which one is line 23? what are you trying to do?

Comment: Before trying to look inside `a` you should check that you didn't exceed the array dimension.  (`mid-k` and `mid+k` should be smaller than zero or greater than `x` in your case). If you read your exception carefully, you'll know exactly what is the problem.

Comment: hey, you are talking pretty Interface Oriented. Only give super Interface/Class information to us....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you might be getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for which Maroun has answered in his comment

> Before trying to look inside a you should check that you didn't exceed
>   the array dimension. (mid-k and mid+k should be smaller than zero or
>   greater than x in your case)

Comment: Also, you need to handle situation when x is typed as an even number.

Comment: anyway I am not sure what you are exactly trying to do in this program; otherwise could have suggested a better way to implement it.

Comment: there is a site called techgig.com there is contest going on i m doing the same question to enhance my skills you can also do that.

Comment: Note that you should check greater **OR EQUAL** to `x`. As Deepak said, this is not a good solution, if you tell us what are you trying to do we can help you more.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar Not happy hearing that.. anyway all the best

Answer (score 1):

In your example `x` is 5. `a` is an array of 5 elements. `mid` is 3.

In your for loop, there will be an iteration when `k` = 2, so `mid+k` = 5. Your array only has elements 0 to 4, so you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.